# Describing a sequence of triplets

Tags: sequences-and-series

I am looking for a concise description of a sequence of triplets.

Consider a triplet of integers $\boldsymbol{q}=(q_1,q_2,q_3)$ such that

$q_1\geq q_2 \geq q_3 , q_1>0$

I am looking for a concise way of describing the set of triplets that would be labelled as:

$Q_{(1,0,0)}=\{(1,0,0)\}$

$Q_{(1,1,0)}=\{(1,0,0),(1,1,0)\}$

$Q_{(1,1,1)}=\{(1,0,0),(1,1,0),(1,1,1)\}$

$Q_{(2,0,0)}=\{(1,0,0),(1,1,0),(1,1,1),(2,0,0)\}$

$\vdots$

$Q_{(3,0,0)}=\{(1,0,0),(1,1,0),(1,1,1),(2,0,0),(2,1,0),(2,1,1),(2,2,0),(2,2,1),(2,2,2),(3,0,0)\}$

I was thinking

$Q_{(q_1,q_2,q_3)}:=\{ (q_1',q_2',q_3'): q_1'q_1^2 + q_2'q_1+q_3' \leq  q_1q_1^2 + q_2q_1+q_3\}$

but not even sure if that works in every case.

Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $Q=\{\langle q_1,q_2,q_3\rangle\in\Bbb Z^+\Bbb N\times\Bbb N:q_1\ge q_2\ge q_3\}$. Let $\preceq$ be the lexicographic order on $Q$: if $\langle q_1,q_2,q_3\rangle,\langle p_1,p_2,p_3\rangle\in Q$, then $\langle q_1,q_2,q_3\rangle\preceq\langle p_1,p_2,p_3\rangle$ iff

- $q_1<p_1$, or
- $q_1=p_1$ and $q_2<p_2$, or
- $q_1=p_1$, $q_2=p_2$, and $q_3\le p_3$.

Now for each $\langle q_1,q_2,q_3\rangle\in Q$ let

$$Q_{\langle q_1,q_2,q_3\rangle}=\{\langle p_1,p_2,p_3\rangle\in Q:\langle p_1,p_2,p_3\rangle\preceq\langle q_1,q_2,q_3\rangle\}\;.$$

Depending on what you’re doing with these triplets, you may find it useful to have defined the order $\preceq$ even apart from the fact that it gives you an easy description of the sets $Q_{\langle q_1,q_2,q_3\rangle}$.

Comment: great thanks :)

Comment: @science404: You're welcome.